# Error using MacOS Mojave Patcher

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I'm attempting to update a MacBookPro8,1 2011 to MacOS Mojave using dosdude's handy tool: http://dosdude1.com/mojave/

After formatting 2 separate 16GB flash drives, using the tool gives me the following error:

[image: Error output screenshot]

Running `diskutil list` gives me the following output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         255.9 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +255.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            78.2 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.7 GB    disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         15.7 GB    disk2s1
```

I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of MacOS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says `disk3` yet that's not in your diskutil info, so you need to be certain which disk you are trying to copy to.

In your `diskutil list`, `disk2` looks a likely candidate, however, it is showing as FDisk [which is a Windows-type MBR, Master Boot Record] & needs to be GUID for a bootable HFS+ partition.

The picture on dosDude's site is wrong. You don't format a partition on your USB stick/SD card you format the entire 'disk' like this…

[image]

Select the overall 'disk' device, not any partition within it, then click Erase & make sure the Format & Scheme are macOS Extended (Journaled) [this is HFS+] & GUID Partition Map [this is essential for it to be bootable]. This will, of course, delete any & all data already on it - again make sure you get the right one.